# Access Alpine to create magic properties from standalone js file

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I try to implement Alpine JS within a existing page.

For that, I'm using the CDN version of Alpine, which I'm loading within my `<head>`:

`<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>`

Now I'm trying to access Alpine from a custom.js file, which is loaded automatically within the footer of my page:

```
Alpine.magic('post', function () {
    return function (url, data = {}) {
        return fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            redirect: 'follow',
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
    }
});
```

Within my content I tried this:

```
<div x-data>
    <h1>Alpine Test</h1>
    <button type="button" @click="$post('/api/users', { name: 'John Doe' })">Add user</button>
</div>
```

By clicking the button, this error occurs:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $post is not defined
```

I've also tried it with window.Alpine, without success.

How can I add magic properties and stuff like that without using modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the [defer attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) the browser executes the script after the document parsing. You have to add the defer attribute to the `custom.js` script as well, or embed the magic definition within an `alpine:init` event listener block:

```
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.magic('post', function () {
        return function (url, data = {}) {
            return fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                redirect: 'follow',
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            });
        }
    });
})
```

This ensures that the magic definition happens only after the Alpine.js core is ready.